# Given Item VS Custom Amount

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, user-centered-design

As a user I'm able to donate money in two different ways: by choosing the amount from the given items, OR in alterative, by typing my custom amount.

How would you better visualize these two options, in order to make it crystal clear for the user one choice precludes the other?

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what exactly is the issue with the current design shown above? It looks OK to me

Comment: From User perspective this looks clear to me. If you want to have more "compact" UI, you could go with placing dropdown with values in right column, and input field for custom in right column.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What I'm trying to achieve is having different solutions and visualizations.

Comment: How many payment choices are there? Does this also have to work on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

#### Try using radio buttons / selectable lozenges to make clear only one choice is available. You can reorder the choices by testing what increases the average donation level.

By separating out the selection process, users will see the result of their choice.

You have an opportunity to surface a vertical list, which works on more constrained viewports, and gives you an opportunity in the final area some positive reinforcement (test this as well)

[image]

If they enter the custom amount, you can calculate an average of how much food their donation amount will buy as well:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is such a good visualization.